# Black screen without cursor after loading bar and before the logo in Vista

Tags: windows, windows-update, black-screen-of-death

Okay. Today Windows installed an update automatically. Please note that I have them turned off, and my friends also say that it still does install updates even if they are turned off, so I am more than sure that it isn't a virus. Well, it installed it and then I got an infinite "Welcome" screen. So I did a hard reset. The animated Windows logo showed up, and then I got a black screen. Hard reset. I tried running the automatic repair - it reported that it fixed the issue. So I rebooted, and straight after the loading bar screen I got a black screen (the screen turned off and after 0.25 seconds it turned on). No cursor, nothing works.

In safe mode, I get a black screen with a cursor. I can't launch task manager.

I have access to all the old Windows files through Ubuntu (I can extract them from Acer recovery thing). How can I find out what files were "updated" during this "update" without Windows?

EDIT2: Other instructions didn't help me. I have no external monitor connected and I have an Intel GMA4500MHD.

EDIT3: Now there is no cursor... Again.

EDIT4: After waiting for 25 minutes, the Windows logo displayed, logged in.

Comment: That's the performance of Mircosoft products... Linux rules!!